# How to access contact on Android for API 17

Tags: java, android, android-contacts

I want to be able to read from contacts to my on my Android application but it doesn't seem achievable for APIs below 23. I intend to use this for API 17. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This code should work in API5 and above, using the enum `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds` you have access to all field.

```
 ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
    Cursor contacts = null;
    try {
        contacts = resolver.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        if (contacts.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                String contactId = contacts.getString(contacts.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

                Cursor emails = null;
                Cursor phones = null;
                try {
                    emails = resolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID
                            + " = " + contactId, null, null);
                    while (emails.moveToNext()) {
                        String email = emails.getString(emails.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
                       object
                    }
                    phones = resolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = " + contactId, null, null);
                    while (phones.moveToNext()) {
                        String number = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                        String displayName = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                       phoneContact object
                    }
                } finally {
                    if (emails != null) {
                        emails.close();
                    }
                    if (phones != null) {
                        phones.close();
                    }
                }

            } while (contacts.moveToNext());
        }
    } finally {
        if (contacts != null) {
            contacts.close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this function. This will give you all the contacts saved in phone

```
 private void getContactList() {
            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
            Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                    null, null, null, null);

            if ((cur != null ? cur.getCount() : 0) > 0) {
                while (cur != null && cur.moveToNext()) {
                    String id = cur.getString(
                            cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                    String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(
                            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

                    if (cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(
                            ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)) > 0) {
                        Cursor pCur = cr.query(
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                                null,
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                                new String[]{id}, null);
                        while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                            String phoneNo = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                            Log.i(TAG, "Name: " + name);
                            Log.i(TAG, "Phone Number: " + phoneNo);
                        }
                        pCur.close();
                    }
                }
            }
            if (cur != null) {
                cur.close();
            }
        }
```